# Confusion with comoving distance and physical distance

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

Suppose that you have a flat universe described by the FRW metric.

$$ds^{2}=-dt^{2}+a^{2}(t)(dx^{2}+dy^{2}+dz^{2})$$

Then if you want to know the distance that a light ray travels from time $t_{e}$ to  the present day $t_{0}$, you can make the following calculation:

$$dt^{2}=a^{2}(t)(dx^{2}+dy^{2}+dz^{2})\equiv a^{2}(t)dr^{2}$$

Then

$$r=\int^{t_{0}}_{t_{e}}\frac{dt}{a(t)}  \tag{1}$$

However if I change of coordinates, such that $x=\alpha x'$, $y=\alpha y'$,$z=\alpha z'$, the comoving distance is

$$r'=\int^{t_{0}}_{t_{e}}\frac{dt}{\alpha a(t)} \tag{2}$$

Then the physical distance using equation (1) is:

$$D_{p}=a(t_{0})r=a(t_{0})\int^{t_{0}}_{t_{e}}\frac{dt}{a(t)}  \tag{3}$$

The physical distance using equation (2) is:
$$D_{p}=a(t_{0})r'=a(t_{0})\int^{t_{0}}_{t_{e}}\frac{dt}{\alpha a(t)} \tag{4}$$

If you look at the equations (3) and (4) they are not equal.

**Questions**

1. I understand that the physical distance is something we can measure so (3) and (4) should be equal. But I can't see where is my mistake.
2. The comoving distance depends of the coordinates that I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed your coordinates, but not the components of your metric.  Remember that under a change of coordinates,

$$g_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow g'_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x'^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x'^\nu} g_{\alpha\beta}$$

In this case, letting $i,j=1,2,3$ be spatial indices,

$$g'_{ij} = \left(\alpha \delta^\alpha_i\right)\left(\alpha \delta^\beta_j\right)g_{\alpha\beta} = \alpha^2 g_{ij}$$

Since $g_{ii}=a(t)^2$, this means that when we change coordinates, $a(t)^2 \rightarrow a'(t)^2 = \alpha^2 a(t)^2$, meaning that
$$ds^2 =\underbrace{-dt^2+a(t)^2(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)}_{(t,x,y,z)\text{ coordintes}}\rightarrow\underbrace{-dt^2+\alpha^2 a(t)^2\left(dx'^2+dy'^2+dz'^2\right)}_{(t,x',y',z')\text{ coordinates}}$$

---

> In the equation number four I have to multiplied by $\alpha a(t)$ instead of $a(t)$?

Yes. When you change coordinate systems, the components of your metric change as well.  $D_p = (\text{scale factor}) \chi$; in your first coordinate system, the scale factor is $a(t)$, and in your second it is $\alpha a(t)$.

Comment: Oh! In the equation number four I have to multiplied by $\alpha a_{0}$ instead of $a_{0}$? @J. Murray

Comment: I think that your last equation should be $ds^{2}=−dt^{2}+\frac{a^{2}}{\alpha^{2}}(dx'^2+dy'^2+dz'^2)$. And my last questions is, the comoving distance depend of the coordinates that I choose?

Comment: @Nothing No, that's not the right expression for $ds^2$ in the coordinates $(t,x',y',z')$. That's the point of my answer - you can't change the *coordinates* without changing the components of the metric too.

Comment: @Nothing I've updated my answer to clear up that confusion.

Comment: Thank you. Then the equations (3) and (4) are the same and that gives me the conclusion that the physical distance is the same for both coordinates. However the comoving distance is not the same for both.

Comment: @Nothing Yes, but just as a warning - generally a comoving coordinate system is chosen such that the scale factor is equal to $1$ at the current cosmological time.  Your scaled coordinate system is equivalent to multiplying $a(t)$ by a constant factor, so this (and similar statements, like the fact that the proper distance and the comoving distance are equal at the present time) will no longer be true.